# error: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Tags: web, deployment, dockerfile, render

Github - https://github.com/harshp807/Movie-Recommendation-Engine

Dockerfile - https://github.com/harshp807/Movie-Recommendation-Engine/blob/main/Dockerfile

While deploying the application on render, I am getting error ->

> error: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir
> -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Can anyone please help me in this and let me know If I am doing any mistake or if my Dockerfile is not correct as per folder structure

Also please let me know, if there is anything else needed

Comment: I voted to close this question because the code with the problem is linked externally. Please [edit] this question to include the [minimal code that exhibits the issue](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly in your question. [Code linked externally may not be permanently available, and may not be licensed such that it can be used in answers](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/).